# Distribution of minimum of first passage time and first return time

Tags: probability, random-walk

Consider two one-dimensional discrete time simple, symmetric random walks on:
**a)** a finite lattice of $L$ sites 
**b)** a finite lattice of $2L-1$ sites

In both cases, once the walker starts from $1$ and when it reaches the right boundary, it reflects back with probability $1$. Is the distribution of first return time in **a)**, the same as distribution of $\min\{$first return to $1$, first passage to $2L-1$ in **b)**$\}$

Problem is **a)**. I feel that **b)** is just Gambler's ruin. Is this reasoning correct? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems like an application of the reflection lemma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The equivalence classes of the states in b) under the reflection symmetry are in bijection with the states in a), and the transition probabilities between these equivalence classes are those of the states in a); thus the return times on these equivalence classes are also the same, and the return time of the equivalence class formed by the two ends is your minimum.

Comment: But in b), once the walker reflects back from L, there's still a positive probability of going beyond L. This is not true in a). So why is it a bijection?

Comment: @SudheeshSurendranath: I don't understand – in b) the walker doesn't reflect back from $L$; in b) $L$ is just a regular site with regular symmetric probabilities? Or do you mean just that the walker goes to $L$ and then back to $L-1$?

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you're saying is that, in b), once the walker reaches L, there's equal probability that it goes above or below L. The set of random walks which go below L after hitting L is in bijection with those in a). Did I get it right?

Comment: @SudheeshSurendranath: You could put it that way, but I chose a different formalization, using the equivalence classes under the reflection symmetry, which to my mind makes it a bit easier to think about. If you project the process onto the equivalence classes, the transition probabilities from one class to another are the sums of the transition probabilities from any of the representatives to all of the representatives (note the use of "any" in one case and "all" in the other). For sites other than $L$, each representative only has transitions to one representative of adjacent classes...

Comment: @SudheeshSurendranath: But the site $L$ is adjacent to two sites in the same class and has transition probability $\frac12$ to each of them, so the sum is $1$, and that's exactly what we need, since that's the transition probability from the reflecting $L$ end to $L-1$ in scenario a).

Comment: This seems like an elegant way to use reflection symmetry. Can you please point me to some references where I can read about the method of using equivalence classes under some symmetry? Maybe some place where a proof using this method has been attempted?

Comment: @StatisticalMechanic: Sorry, I don't know of any; I just made that up on the spot...